# How to add a completely new assets folder in a rails 5 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

Ok so i tried to implement a web template ( [this one](https://coderthemes.com/adminto/?storefront=envato-elements) ) in a rails app, Now it works perfectly fine in development but when i deploy it on heroku i only get text and no formatting.

I've added the assets folder of the web template in the "assets" folder of the rails app and you can see the file structure below but i do not understand how to add it to the asset pipeline or how do i get it to work in production

[image: file structure]

The result i get in development is like this 
[image]

The result i get after deploying on heroku is [like this](https://knacksack.herokuapp.com/) 
[image]

i searched a lot of questions and alot of articles but there is no clear guide on how to do this

in my view layout "application.html.erb" i've tried both of the following paths but none of them works

```
 <!-- App css -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/css/icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/css/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and this

```
 <!-- App css -->
        <link href="assets/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/assets/css/icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/assets/css/app.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

my **assets.rb**

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
# Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')

Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "assets","css")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "assets","data")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "assets","fonts")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "assets","images")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "assets","js")
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "assets","libs")
```

My **production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  # config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "KnackSack_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Comment: You should use stylesheet_link_tag for your css files

Comment: @Eyeslandic doing that actually breaks the website

Comment: How are you doing it?

Comment: @Eyeslandic do i need to add every file in a `config.assets.precompile += ....... ` cause the css files work if i add all 3 in assets.precompile

Comment: All files under `assets` are automatically included, Just do `stylesheet_link_tag 'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'` in your view